# [Android,Facebook,Infer]Too many open files about infer error

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-infer

I use Facebook's Infer to check my android code

```
infer -- ./gradlew build
after 8 minutes

Fatal error: exception Sys_error("/Users/lm/project/android_workplace/******/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.mogujie/user/1.2.17/jars/classes.jar: Too many open files")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lm/project/infer_workplace/infer-osx-v0.4.0/infer/bin/infer", line 180, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/lm/project/infer_workplace/infer-osx-v0.4.0/infer/bin/infer", line 144, in main
    capture_exitcode = imported_module.gen_instance(args, cmd).capture()
  File "/Users/lm/project/infer_workplace/infer-osx-v0.4.0/infer/bin/../lib/capture/gradle.py", line 83, in capture
    return util.run_commands(cmds)
  File "/Users/lm/project/infer_workplace/infer-osx-v0.4.0/infer/bin/../lib/capture/util.py", line 40, in run_commands
    if not cmd.start():
  File "/Users/lm/project/infer_workplace/infer-osx-v0.4.0/infer/bin/inferlib.py", line 692, in start
    if self.capture() == os.EX_OK:
  File "/Users/lm/project/infer_workplace/infer-osx-v0.4.0/infer/bin/inferlib.py", line 478, in capture
    return self.run_infer_frontend()
  File "/Users/lm/project/infer_workplace/infer-osx-v0.4.0/infer/bin/inferlib.py", line 469, in run_infer_frontend
    self.args.analyzer
  File "/Users/lm/project/infer_workplace/infer-osx-v0.4.0/infer/bin/inferlib.py", line 385, in run_command
    raise e
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '[u'/Users/lm/project/infer_workplace/infer-osx-v0.4.0/infer/bin/InferJava', u'-project_root', '/Users/lm/project/android_workplace/Minicooper4android', u'-results_dir', u'/Users/lm/project/android_workplace/Minicooper4android/infer-out', u'-verbose_out', '/var/folders/2r/7hc18jz1091_jg7_8jcnqlhr0000gn/T/javac_qWbfkP.out', u'-models', u'/Users/lm/project/infer_workplace/infer-osx-v0.4.0/infer/bin/../lib/java/models.jar', u'-no-static_final']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

From http://fbinfer.com/support

> The maximum number of files a program can simultaneously hold open is a bit low on MacOs. You can increase the limit by running these commands for example:

```
sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=20480
sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=22480
ulimit -S -n 2048
```